# How can I change the predefined comment character '#' in the Python Interpreter?

Tags: python

I am working on a musical information manipulation tool package. I cant use the '#' for a part of any variable identifier, because it's for comments, and this is a part of the language. But the '#' symbol has different but very important use in musicology, e.g. C#4 mean the middle C sharp. In my plans, the user should be able to user musical terminology to operate in python console, like:

```
if key.tonic is C#4:
```

So, I am wondering is there any possible way to go around this limitation? Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: if you're using it as a variable, why not substitute # to characters like `c_sharp_4`?

Comment: first, C#4 is more familiar to music theorist. second, it much more short than c_sharp_4, you know, we just don't like type too much. by the way, the flat-'b', double sharp-'x', double flat-'bb', even natural-'n', all of it except '#' are possible in python.

Comment: Then I guess using strings to check equality makes the most sense in your case.

Comment: # is not the sharp symbol. You should be using ♯ instead. Of course, that's not valid in a Python identifier, either. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redefine language constructs in python (or any other language).

You **might** be able to if you downloaded the python source code and recompiled a version without comment support or something - but that's probably out of scope of what you are trying to achieve (and would require that version of python to run, so it wouldn't be portable).

Instead, consider using `s` or something instead of the `#` symbol. I have seen many people use `b` in lieu of `♭`, so this isn't unusual. I think most readers would find `Cs4` pretty intuitive, and if you don't then you can always leave a comment next to it :)

An alternate solution depending on how you are using it, could involve a python dictionary. You could store all of your notes in it, and reference it like this;

```
notes["C#4"]
```

But that will depend on your usecase.

Comment: in fact, i am thinking about using the 'Cs4' plan, thank you.

Comment: That's what I would do. Please consider upvoting and marking this answer as accepted if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely **have to** have objects with # in the displayed name you could use a naming convention such as c_sharp_4 to use in your code but override the **print** & **repr** members to print it as C#4.

In python 3 you can, provided your terminal is set up with a utf-8 font actually use the Unicode sharp, flat and natural characters \u266f, \u266d & \u266e:

```
In [9]: print('C\u266f B\u266d F\u266e')

C♯ B♭ F♮
```

Which to a pure music theorist would presumably be preferable as the hash character # is *not* the same as the sharp *♯*.

You cannot, however, use any of these modifiers as a part of a variable or object name as the rule is that the first character must be an underscore or letter and the subsequent ones must all be one of these or a number.

Comment: it’s really instructive, though it only resolve the displaying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting it as a string? Ie.
If key.tonic is "C#4":

Comment: yes, I had thought about that. but it means i will have to type many many quotation mark.